# Transfer objects between two states in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating a shopping cart with react hooks that looks like this

```
const ShoppingCart = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([
        {id: 1, name: 'Product 1', price: 2500},
        {id: 2, name: 'Product 2', price: 2000},
        {id: 3, name: 'Product 3', price: 2500},
    ])

    const [cart, setCart] = useState()


    const addToCart = (item) => (
        setCart([cart, {item}])
        // setCart([...cart, {item}])
        // setCart([{item}])
    )

    return (
              {
                    products.map((product, i) => (
                        <>
                        <Product name={product.name} price={product.price} key={product.id} />
                        <button 
                            value='Add to cart' 
                            // onClick={((product) => setCart(...cart, product))}
                            onClick={(product) => addToCart(product)}
                            // onClick={console.log(i)}
                            />
                            {console.log(cart)}
                        </>
                    ))
                }
    )
}
```

The lines commented out are some of the things I had tried that didn't work. Also tried it without the second arg[i] in the lamda function within map.

I'm trying to add a product to the cart object after a user clicks the button

The expected state of cart for example if the user clicks the button next to the product with id of one would be

```
[{id: 1, name:'Product 1', price: 2500}]
```

If it would be possible, I would also like to add another field to the object which would be amount

Comment: You need to define initial state, even if it's just an empty array: const [cart, setCart] = useState([])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the initial value of the cart

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([]); // [] is the initial value of the cart
```

remove `product` from the callback passed to `onClick` because it's not the product, it's the `click event`

```
<button value="Add to cart" onClick={() => addToCart(product)} />
```

and the spread operator should work fine

```
const addToCart = item => {
    setCart([...cart, item]);
};
```

**EDIT**

if you want to add the item only once, check if it exists in the cart first :

```
const addToCart = item => {
  const ndx = cart.findIndex(e => e.id === item.id);
  if (ndx === -1) {
    setCart([...cart, item]);
  }
};
```

Comment: This is exactly what was needed!

Comment: Please would you know of a way to add check if an item already exists in the array?

Comment: so you won't add the asme item twice ?

Comment: It's possible to add the same twice but it should show like 2x, 3x etc depending on the amount and also read the length of the array including the amount of items within like  `<p>{cart.length} items in cart</p>`

Answer (score 2):

please use ...cart in your addToCart function because cart would be previous data array and when you do like that [...cart,item] then Previous array would merge in new array and will add new product object in that new array.

```
 const addToCart = (item) => (
    setCart([...cart,item])
)
```

and please don't pass param to your click callback function because you are getting this product from above not from click function .use anonymous function like this

```
 onClick={() => addToCart(product)}
```

Comment: Please would you know of a way to add check if an item already exists in the array?

Comment: you can use array.includes to check if that value exist an array or not

Answer (score 0):

use `onClick={((product) => setCart([...cart, product]))}`